# Switch Glyphicons When Dropdown Menu Opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a long navigation menu with dropdowns and submenus. I'm using an arrow pointing down on my mobile menu to let someone know then can click to expand the submenu. Once someone clicks, I want to replace

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

with

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Can anyone share simple javascript snippet to switch out the icons?

Thank you!

Here is a link http://ws2.5giants.com/

Answer (score 4):

You are using Twitter Bootstrap. As it already includes `jQuery`, use the below code.

Since you have many downward arrow glyphicons on the page, target only the elements inside the `.menuli` and `.dropdown-menu a`

```
$('.menuli, .dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
  $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down'); // Remove on first click, add on second
  $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up'); // Add on first click, remove on second
});
```

Comment: This should be the right answer... I've got this in there now but it still doesn't work. Any ideas why? http://ws2.5giants.com/

Comment: You have enclosed many snippets inside `<script>` Try organizing all the snippets into one `<script></script>` Try that! If that doesn't work, I will let you know. Otherwise try creating a new `.js` file and call that after jQuery file in the header. Check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site

Comment: Manoj, thank you again for your help. That didn't seem to do the trick either. I moved my js to a custom.js file. Eveyrthing else works, but replacing the icons doesn't. Weird. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have updated my code, in the previous version the toggle works only when clicked on the icon. This time it will work if you click on the bar.

Comment: You might see some misalignment while toggling. It is because you have some custom CSS rules set for `glyphicon-menu-down` in `style.css`

Comment: Thanks Manoj. It's mostly working now. Strangely, the sub-menu glyphicons are switching while the menu ones aren't.  For example "Sample" doesn't change, but "Vendor 1" does. Any ideas?

Comment: Not so sure about that. But it is working from my end. Did you update the new code yet? :)

Comment: Yeah it's in there. Try clicking "Sample". The arrow should switch when the submenu opens. It's working properly on the Vendor links within the Sample menu

Comment: It seems like a different problem since multiple events are firing on that dropdown, like collapse. Please open a new question since its context is different.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend putting it all in a div with an id of "menu-glyphicon" or something like that. Then you can write this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-glyphicon span').click(function (){
        $('.glyphicon').removeClass('.glyphicon-menu-down');
        $('.glyphicon').addClass('.glyphicon-menu-up');
    })
}
```

Comment: You didn't specify a trigger or any reverse functionality? What happens when this menu closes?